# Using appSettings key from web.config in NavigateUrl property

Tags: asp.net

I have  a string in my web.config:

```
<configuration>

    <appSettings>

        <add key="email1" value="mailto:info@site1.ru" />


    </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

I want to use that setting in that way (see below):

```
<p>Write me here: <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink503" runat="server" 
        NavigateUrl=<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["email1"] %>>my e-mail</asp:HyperLink>.</p>
```

However, i get an error. I tried to use a quotes in NavigateUrl, but I get same error. Please, correct my code so it can works.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please post your error

Comment: GrooV, i have two sections in my web.config with customErrors and httpErrors. Both sections redirect to 404.aspx in case of any errors. I don't know hot to get a speific error code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a special notation for getting app settings. Also, you had an extra closing bracket.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink503" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<% $appSettings:email1 %>' Text="my e-mail" />
```

or

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink503" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<% $appSettings:email1 %>'>my e-mail</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Great, it works. What if email1 = info@site1.ru and I want to set a NavigateUrl to mailto:email1 ? How to do concatenation ?

Comment: In that case, do something like Yuriy's answer. Put it in the Page_Load function probably. `HyperLink503.NavigateUrl = "mailto:" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["email1"];` I couldn't figure out how to do it inline with concatenation.

Comment: mason, ok. I just will make email2 for that case.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you cannot use `<% ... %>` in server-side controls. As an alternative I suggest setting the value in code behind (e.g. in page load event):

```
HyperLink503.NavigateUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["email1"];
```

Comment: You can use `<% ... %>` in server controls, although your way works too.

Comment: Yup. Nice one about $appSettings